# Are there tools for importing from CSV to BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, tools, csv

I'm seeking a way to get my books database, stored on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/), into BibTeX form. As near as I can tell, Goodreads provides no support for this directly, but does provide for [CSV export](http://www.goodreads.com/review/import) (on the right). Are there tools I could used to import from the CSV file into BibTeX?

---

FWIW, the fields exported by goodreads are

```
Book Id,Title,Author,Author l-f,Additional Authors,ISBN,ISBN13,My Rating,Average Rating,Publisher,Binding,Number of Pages,Year Published,Original Publication Year,Date Read,Date Added,Bookshelves,Bookshelves with positions,Exclusive Shelf,My Review,Spoiler,Private Notes,Read Count,Recommended For,Recommended By,Owned Copies,Original Purchase Date,Original Purchase Location,Condition,Condition Description,BCID
```

and I can, of course, easily rearrange their order or convert to other delimiters.

Comment: It seems you can set up a custom import filter for [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net) for such a thing: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CustomImports.php

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That has possibilities; but ideally I'd like to avoid writing Java code.

Comment: I would write a small AWK script to do that. You can probably equally easy accomplish the task using Tcl, Perl, Python, or Ruby (I know Python and barely some Perl). I would definitely not use JabRef and I would refuse to program in Java even if you point a gun into my my head.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: I agree! Fortunately it turns out that [a bit of bash and the Web](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48664/7844) did the job.

Comment: https://www.freefileconvert.com/csv-bib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't give complete answer, but some suggestions (it would have to be really worked on to make it complete).

There are tools:

- [**xml2bib** from **bibutils**](http://sourceforge.net/p/bibutils/home/xml2bib/)
- [**csv2xml**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csv2xml/)

The problem is that **xml2bib** needs a very special format called [Metadata Object Description Schema: MODS](http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/mods-guidance.html).

Below, I give example file of my thesis `.bib` bibliography, converted to the correct `.xml` **MODS format** by **bib2xml** and coverted back to a `.bib` file by **xml2bib**. It illustrates how complicated the XML format is:

I apologize for the long file listings but I don't have a reliable online file storage.

```
@book{beardon,
    AUTHOR = {Beardon, Alan F.},
     TITLE = {The geometry of discrete groups},
    SERIES = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {91},
      NOTE = {Corrected reprint of the 1983 original},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1995},
     PAGES = {xii+337},
      ISBN = {0-387-90788-2},
 XXMRCLASS = {22E40 (11F06 20H15 30F35 57N10)},
XXMRNUMBER = {1393195 (97d:22011)},
}

@article{ford,
    AUTHOR = {Ford, Lester R.},
     TITLE = {The fundamental region for a {F}uchsian group},
   JOURNAL = {Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  FJOURNAL = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
    VOLUME = {31},
      YEAR = {1925},
    NUMBER = {9-10},
     PAGES = {531--539},
      ISSN = {0002-9904},
 XXMRCLASS = {Contributed Item},
XXMRNUMBER = {1561111},
       DOI = {10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X},
}

@article{k:sr_rmg,
    AUTHOR = {K{\r{u}}rka, Petr},
     TITLE = {A symbolic representation of the real {M}\"obius group},
   JOURNAL = {Nonlinearity},
  FJOURNAL = {Nonlinearity},
    VOLUME = {21},
      YEAR = {2008},
    NUMBER = {3},
     PAGES = {613--623},
      ISSN = {0951-7715},
     CODEN = {NONLE5},
 XXMRCLASS = {37F30 (37B10)},
XXMRNUMBER = {2396619 (2009j:37073)},
MRREVIEWER = {Jiri Fiser},
       DOI = {10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012},
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modsCollection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
<mods ID="beardon">
    <titleInfo>
        <title>The geometry of discrete groups</title>
    </titleInfo>
    <name type="personal">
        <namePart type="given">Alan</namePart>
        <namePart type="given">F</namePart>
        <namePart type="family">Beardon</namePart>
        <role>
            <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">author</roleTerm>
        </role>
    </name>
    <originInfo>
        <issuance>monographic</issuance>
        <dateIssued>1995</dateIssued>
        <publisher>Springer-Verlag</publisher>
        <place>
            <placeTerm type="text">New York</placeTerm>
        </place>
    </originInfo>
    <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource>
    <genre authority="marcgt">book</genre>
    <relatedItem type="host">
        <titleInfo>
            <title>Graduate Texts in Mathematics</title>
        </titleInfo>
    </relatedItem>
    <note>Corrected reprint of the 1983 original</note>
    <identifier type="isbn">0-387-90788-2</identifier>
    <identifier type="citekey">beardon</identifier>
    <part>
        <detail type="volume"><number>91</number></detail>
    </part>
</mods>
<mods ID="ford">
    <titleInfo>
        <title>The fundamental region for a Fuchsian group</title>
    </titleInfo>
    <name type="personal">
        <namePart type="given">Lester</namePart>
        <namePart type="given">R</namePart>
        <namePart type="family">Ford</namePart>
        <role>
            <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">author</roleTerm>
        </role>
    </name>
    <originInfo>
        <dateIssued>1925</dateIssued>
    </originInfo>
    <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource>
    <relatedItem type="host">
        <titleInfo>
            <title>Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.</title>
        </titleInfo>
        <originInfo>
            <issuance>continuing</issuance>
        </originInfo>
        <genre authority="marcgt">periodical</genre>
        <genre>academic journal</genre>
        <identifier type="issn">0002-9904</identifier>
    </relatedItem>
    <identifier type="citekey">ford</identifier>
    <identifier type="doi">10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X</identifier>
    <location>
        <url>http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X</url>
    </location>
    <part>
        <date>1925</date>
        <detail type="volume"><number>31</number></detail>
        <detail type="number"><number>9-10</number></detail>
        <extent unit="page">
            <start>531</start>
            <end>539</end>
        </extent>
    </part>
</mods>
<mods ID="k:sr_rmg">
    <titleInfo>
        <title>A symbolic representation of the real Möbius group</title>
    </titleInfo>
    <name type="personal">
        <namePart type="given">Petr</namePart>
        <namePart type="family">K\rurka</namePart>
        <role>
            <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">author</roleTerm>
        </role>
    </name>
    <originInfo>
        <dateIssued>2008</dateIssued>
    </originInfo>
    <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource>
    <relatedItem type="host">
        <titleInfo>
            <title>Nonlinearity</title>
        </titleInfo>
        <originInfo>
            <issuance>continuing</issuance>
        </originInfo>
        <genre authority="marcgt">periodical</genre>
        <genre>academic journal</genre>
        <identifier type="issn">0951-7715</identifier>
    </relatedItem>
    <identifier type="citekey">k:sr_rmg</identifier>
    <identifier type="doi">10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012</identifier>
    <location>
        <url>http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012</url>
    </location>
    <part>
        <date>2008</date>
        <detail type="volume"><number>21</number></detail>
        <detail type="number"><number>3</number></detail>
        <extent unit="page">
            <start>613</start>
            <end>623</end>
        </extent>
    </part>
</mods>
</modsCollection>
```

---

```
@Book{beardon,
author="Beardon, Alan F.",
title="The geometry of discrete groups",
series="Graduate Texts in Mathematics",
year="1995",
publisher="Springer-Verlag",
address="New York",
volume="91",
note="Corrected reprint of the 1983 original",
isbn="0-387-90788-2"
}

@Article{ford,
author="Ford, Lester R.",
title="The fundamental region for a Fuchsian group",
journal="Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.",
year="1925",
volume="31",
number="9-10",
pages="531--539",
issn="0002-9904",
doi="10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X",
url="http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1925-04104-X"
}

@Article{k:sr_rmg,
author="K{\backslash}rurka, Petr",
title="A symbolic representation of the real M{\"o}bius group",
journal="Nonlinearity",
year="2008",
volume="21",
number="3",
pages="613--623",
issn="0951-7715",
doi="10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012",
url="http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/21/3/012"
}
```

---

Now: The following is an input file with header and one bibliography item (containing for each field the filed name with `abc...xyz` dummy text). I believe that the output XML file could be converted into the **MODS format**, but I'm not sure how and it will be a lot of work. The why that I thought of is replacing each string of the form `<Title>` to the string of XML markups that stands before the Title in the correct format.

```
Book Id,Title,Author,Author l-f,Additional Authors,ISBN,ISBN13,My Rating,Average Rating,Publisher,Binding,Number of Pages,Year Published,Original Publication Year,Date Read,Date Added,Bookshelves,Bookshelves with positions,Exclusive Shelf,My Review,Spoiler,Private Notes,Read Count,Recommended For,Recommended By,Owned Copies,Original Purchase Date,Original Purchase Location,Condition,Condition Description,BCID
abcBook Idxyz,abcTitlexyz,abcAuthorxyz,abcAuthor l-fxyz,abcAdditional Authorsxyz,abcISBNxyz,abcISBN13xyz,abcMy Ratingxyz,abcAverage Ratingxyz,abcPublisherxyz,abcBindingxyz,abcNumber of Pagesxyz,abcYear Publishedxyz,abcOriginal Publication Yearxyz,abcDate Readxyz,abcDate Addedxyz,abcBookshelvesxyz,abcBookshelves with positionsxyz,abcExclusive Shelfxyz,abcMy Reviewxyz,abcSpoilerxyz,abcPrivate Notesxyz,abcRead Countxyz,abcRecommended
```

---

```
<row>
  <Book_Id>abcBook Idxyz</Book_Id>
  <Title>abcTitlexyz</Title>
  <Author>abcAuthorxyz</Author>
  <Author_l_f>abcAuthor l-fxyz</Author_l_f>
  <Additional_Authors>abcAdditional Authorsxyz</Additional_Authors>
  <ISBN>abcISBNxyz</ISBN>
  <ISBN13>abcISBN13xyz</ISBN13>
  <My_Rating>abcMy Ratingxyz</My_Rating>
  <Average_Rating>abcAverage Ratingxyz</Average_Rating>
  <Publisher>abcPublisherxyz</Publisher>
  <Binding>abcBindingxyz</Binding>
  <Number_of_Pages>abcNumber of Pagesxyz</Number_of_Pages>
  <Year_Published>abcYear Publishedxyz</Year_Published>
  <Original_Publication_Year>abcOriginal Publication Yearxyz</Original_Publication_Year>
  <Date_Read>abcDate Readxyz</Date_Read>
  <Date_Added>abcDate Addedxyz</Date_Added>
  <Bookshelves>abcBookshelvesxyz</Bookshelves>
  <Bookshelves_with_positions>abcBookshelves with positionsxyz</Bookshelves_with_positions>
  <Exclusive_Shelf>abcExclusive Shelfxyz</Exclusive_Shelf>
  <My_Review>abcMy Reviewxyz</My_Review>
  <Spoiler>abcSpoilerxyz</Spoiler>
  <Private_Notes>abcPrivate Notesxyz</Private_Notes>
  <Read_Count>abcRead Countxyz</Read_Count>
  <Recommended_For>abcRecommended Forxyz</Recommended_For>
  <Recommended_By>abcRecommended Byxyz</Recommended_By>
  <Owned_Copies>abcOwned Copiesxyz</Owned_Copies>
  <Original_Purchase_Date>abcOriginal Purchase Datexyz</Original_Purchase_Date>
  <Original_Purchase_Location>abcOriginal Purchase Locationxyz</Original_Purchase_Location>
  <Condition>abcConditionxyz</Condition>
  <Condition_Description>abcCondition Descriptionxyz</Condition_Description>
  <BCID>abcBCIDxyz</BCID>
</row>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Zotero**
I do not use `Goodreads`, but I suggest that you try [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/), and see if Zotero can import directly. Maybe it is able to fetch all your books directly in one operation. [Zotero standalone](http://www.zotero.org/support/3.0) works with different browser and on different platforms.

Try it, it is free so you do not waste any money.

**MarcEdit + Bibutils**
A two step solution is using [MarcEdit](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~reeset/marcedit/html/index.php): You can import a delimited file (*f.ex.* CSV) directly. Then it is just to save it to any suitable format supported by your .bib-file manager. If you need to clean up or manipulate the CSV-files, you can use Sam Franche’s [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/).

> *Complete solution*: Import your CSV-files into `MarcEdit`. Save as `MODS`-file. You can then use `bibutils` to convert from MODS-format into bibtex, as recommended by *tohecz*.

You can also import a MODS-file exported from MarcEdit into Zotero, clean it up and export it to `bibtex`-format.

**Jabref**
[Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) can import several formats, but I am not absolute sure any of those can be exported from MarcEdit. `JabRef` also read from SQL databases (MySQL etc). You can import your CSV-files into a MySQL table, let JabRef import it and export it as an .bib-file.

Comment: Ad MarcEdit: Do you know any such "suitable format"?

Comment: I don't argue, I asked about MarcEdit.

Comment: ... then I think that MarcEdit+bibutils can provide a complete solution for the original poster ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since the CSV has an ISBN for each book, and since all of the information I need for BibTeX can be [reconstructed from the ISBN](http://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/), all I need to do is use the ISBN column from the CSV to create an array, and then generate a file containing the corresponding BibTeX information:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Generate a BibTeX bibliography from an array of ISBNs

array=(<pasted column of ISBNs>)

rm goodreads.bib
for isbn in "${isbnarray[@]}"
do
    curl http://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/isbn-service?isbn=$isbn >> goodreads.bib
done
```

And that's it.

Comment: No worries. I'm still interested in a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Tellico](http://tellico-project.org/) can import from csv and then exporto to bibtex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, and thank you for sharing your answer! If you want, you can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simplest solutions and more trustfull I think.
In https://doi.org/ you have all the DOIs registered, and the website just have bib format return.
If you access `https://doi.org/$doi`, you get all the informations releated.

So, you can use as follow:

```
doi="10.1007/978-3-319-46031-4_16"
curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex; charset=utf-8" https://doi.org/$doi
```

And you get:

```
@incollection{Solberg_2016,
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-46031-4_16},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-319-46031-4_16},
    year = 2016,
    month = {dec},
    publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
    pages = {147--149},
    author = {Arnor Solberg and Peter Matthews},
    title = {Conclusion and Future Research},
    booktitle = {Model-Driven Development and Operation of Multi-Cloud Applications}
}
```

In my case, I needed to convert because Springer doesnt have bib format to export.
So I export to CSV, isolated DOI column and save in a file named doi.txt (1 DOI per line) and then, I created a simplest script.

```
for doi in `cat doi.txt`
    do echo "Downloading line > $doi"
    curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex; charset=utf-8" https://doi.org/$doi >> result.bib;
done
```

Comment: I know that is a beginner question, but... What can I do to run this script? "for doi in `cat doi.txt` do echo "Downloading line > $doi" curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex; charset=utf-8" https://doi.org/$doi >> result.bib;" Thanks!

Comment: @LucasBonino This script runs in command prompt. Press Windows Key+R key in windows and write cmd.exe, consequently press Enter to launch command prompt. Then paste the above script. Modify it to as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[image]enter image description here

If you use zotero, add items by identifier as on picture - simply - insert into doi values separated by "," as follows:
10.1007/s11831-022-09729-4, 10.1007/978-3-030-85739-4