# create bib files from csv

Tags: csv

I have bibliographical references ordered in a spreadsheet and I want to create a .bib file to use then in latex documents. I have found the way to transforma a .bib file into a csv, but not the inverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there tools for importing from CSV to BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48532/are-there-tools-for-importing-from-csv-to-bibtex)